# How do I make it so my Chrome extension only needs to be clicked once to activate the default-popup?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

#### Information:

I am making a extension for Google Chrome which injects a Calendar event on button click from inside a `button-popup.html` file which appears when the extension icon is clicked.

At the moment, when I install the extension for the first time, for some reason clicking the first time on the icon in the Chrome taskbar appears to do nothing - I need to click the icon a second time for the `HTML` page defined as the `default-popup` in the manifest file to appear.

I've looked through the extension documentation but am unable to find anything relevant.

#### Question:

*Is there a setting which I have overlooked that needs to be added to my `manifest.json` file so that the `default-popup` appears on first click rather than the second?*

#### Code:

**`manifest.json`:**

```json
{
   "name": "My Chrome Extension",
   "key": "redacted-key",
   "version": "0.0.4",
   "description": "Cool information about my extension",
   "permissions": ["identity"],
   "background": {
     "scripts": [
       "background.js"
     ]
   },

   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'redacted-hash' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self' ",

   "browser_action": {
     "default-popup": "button-popup.html"
   },
   "oauth2": {
     "client_id": "redacted-client-id",
     "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    ]
  },

   "icons": {
     "16": "16.png",
     "32": "32.png",
     "48": "48.png",
     "128": "128.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**`background.js:`**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: 'button-popup.html'});
});
```

Comment: Try adding "activeTab" to "permissions" array in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Added and reloaded extension but the behaviour hasn't changed; I still need to click the icon twice to view the `default-popup`. I think `activeTab` is only needed if I want to [access the active tab when the extension is clicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab), rather than having an effect on the `html` file that opens on button click.

Comment: My idea was that Chrome showed the icon in "wants access to active tab" mode because there are no other API-specific reason for the behavior you describe. Which probably means there's a bug in your code that shows the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ah good point - I hadn't looked at that. I shall look again at chrome methods but until then I have updated my post with `background.js` for visibility.

Comment: 1) it's simply a typo: `default-popup` should be `default_popup` in manifest.json. 2) browserAction.onClicked won't work in the background script when default_popup is specified (because it's not needed - you can put the code in popup js).

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah that's it, just an oversight on my part, thank you so much. Throw it in an answer an I can accept you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This was just a typo - as pointed out by wOxxOm in the comments, `default-popup` should be `default_popup`.*

#### Refernces:

- [chrome.browserAction: Popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups)